# Redirecting Form URL for Forms

Tags: redirect

I have a form that users go into and have to add information to fields before they can proceed to approve/reject the task process. My thought to make this happen with a better flow is to redirect the URL by changing the source URL in the Edit Form since that is what they will be accessing.

However, I change the source link for the Edit Form, and the transition works fine the first time, and then it reverts back to the Form List that shows all of the information. It won't stick on the "Add New Item" form either.

Here's the source url I am putting in:

```
source=https://<oursite>/sites/hhc/finance/ap/Lists/Workflow%20Tasks/AllItems.aspx
```

Does anyone see something wrong or have any suggestions?